# Append elements of list to other list in Prolog

Tags: list, prolog

I'm trying to learn Prolog and got stuck on a very simple problem.
I need a function that will take one list and appends its elements to other list creating list of lists from them.

Lets say `list1=[A,B]` and `list2=[0,1,2]`. I need to generate `list3=[[A,B,0],[A,B,1],[A,B,2]]`.

I thought there would be a function that works like this as it looks really simple. I didn't found anything useful, so I wanted to implement it but I couldn't even do that. I got stuck with "iterating" over the list and got it only working when list2 would be just an atom using maplist.

If anyone could show me how to do that I would be very grateful. Thank you.

Comment: Hint: use `append/3`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem OP wants to end with list of list and not a single level list.

Comment: @GuyCoder: yes, you can make a variant of `append/3` that can be used in `maplist/3` :)

Comment: I'll look into it if I find anything useful it looks a bit similar, but it's a different problem.

Comment: That sounds like something for `maplist/3`. Take a look [at my notes](https://github.com/dtonhofer/prolog_notes/blob/master/maplist_3_examples.md).

Comment: Thank you, that actually solves my problem. I didn't know the first argument can be so complex. You notes explain it very well.